# Setting style during table creation in postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, style

Is there any way to set a style from public.layer_styles table to a postgis table while creation?

Comment: What code are you using to create the table?  I think that should be part of your very brief question.

Comment: are you using QGIS or ArcGIS?

Comment: I am creating using pgSQL

Comment: @LaughU: i have done it using QGIS but need to do it dynamically during table creation using pgSQL

Comment: This can be done with an event trigger in Postgres.  If @PolyGeo wants to re-open this, I can provide an answer.

Comment: @dbaston it's re-opened now for you to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent version of Postgres let you perform actions automatically after data definition language (DDL) changes such as `CREATE TABLE` using [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html).  Here's a skeleton for an event trigger that will insert appropriate data into `layer_styles` every time a spatial table is created.

First, we create an event trigger function.  It's similar to a regular trigger but has access to different variables and functions, reflecting the special context in which it's executed.  In this case we use the `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands` function to get the name of the created table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_layer_style()
RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
  table_catalog   text;
  table_schema    text;
  table_name      text;
  geometry_column text;
  tbl_id          oid;
BEGIN

table_catalog := current_database();
table_schema := (pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()).schema_name;
tbl_id := (pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()).objid;
EXECUTE 'SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid=$1' USING tbl_id INTO table_name;

FOR geometry_column IN EXECUTE 'SELECT f_geometry_column FROM public.geometry_columns WHERE f_table_catalog=$1 AND f_table_schema=$2 AND f_table_name=$3' 
  USING table_catalog, table_schema, table_name LOOP
    -- INSERT INTO public.layer_styles
    -- (f_table_catalog, f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, ...)
    -- VALUES
    -- (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, geometry_column, ...)
END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, we bind the trigger to all `CREATE TABLE` events in the database:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER style_adder
  ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_layer_style();
```

To use this, you'd need to update the commented section of the trigger function to specify what data should be added to the remainder of the columns in `layer_styles`.